# operator== and list::remove()

Tags: c++, pointers, tr1

**Test.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <memory>

template <class Type>
bool operator==(const std::weak_ptr<Type>& wp1, const std::weak_ptr<Type>& wp2)
{
std::shared_ptr<Type> sp1;

if(!wp1.expired())
    sp1 = wp1.lock();

std::shared_ptr<Type> sp2;

if(!wp2.expired())
    sp2 = wp2.lock();

return sp1 == sp2;
}

#endif
```

**Test.cpp**

```
#include "Test.h"
#include <list>


int main()
{
typedef std::list< std::weak_ptr<int> > intList;

std::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int(5));
std::weak_ptr<int> wp(sp);

intList myList;
myList.push_back(wp);

myList.remove(wp); //Problem
}
```

The program won't compile due to myList.remove():

> 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   10.0\vc\include\list(1194): error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type
>   'std::tr1::weak_ptr<_Ty>' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 1>
>   with 1>          [ 1>              _Ty=int 1>          ]

But you can see the following defined in Test.h:

```
bool operator==(const std::weak_ptr<Type>& wp1, const std::weak_ptr<Type>& wp2)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: not sure, but can you try to define the bool operator== with const references?

Comment: Whoops, I had it that way originally and forgot to change it back. Same problem with const references.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operator overload is found by [argument-dependent lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup), and your function doesn't apply as it's not defined in namespace `std` (the namespace of the argument types, and the context of the expression inside `std::list::remove`).

You should use `remove_if` to apply a custom predicate function. In general, don't attempt to define operators for types inside libraries you cannot modify.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. I would like to avoid this altogether but I need to remove from a list of weak_ptrs. Would it be a bad idea to define operator== inside namespace std? I have only used remove_if with a unary predicate with the element itself as an argument. I would need to compare the element with the pointer I am trying to remove. Is it possible to call the predicate with a second argument?

Comment: You could replace your `remove` with `myList.remove_if(std::bind(std::operator==<int>, wp, std::placeholders::_1));`, although I'd rename the comparison function from `operator==` to something like `equals`.  Or you could use a lambda function in place of `std::bind`.

Comment: [`std::list::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) only takes one argument which is the predicate, so you don't need the iterators.  You're maybe thinking of the general [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) defined in `<algorithm>`, which has slightly different behaviour to `list`'s.  See the "Notes" section in the link.  And yes, _1 is the placeholder for each element passed by `remove_if` into the bound function, so your `equals` function looks good as is.